# Arduino, to receive data from client and put the chars, of data, in three different string

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char, tcpclient

In Arduino i have this code:

```
 WiFiClient client = server.available();
     if (!client) {
        return;
      }
    while (client.available()){
    char d = (char)client.read();
    // In this part save to the string
    }
```

i recive this string:

```
true,167*FFFFD19F/
```

i want put the character into a three different string, as:

```
String1 = "true"
String2 = "167"
String3 = "FFFFD19F"
```

Comment: Looks like  you need to parse the string.  Also this looks suspiciously like C++.

Comment: As you read one char at a time, you could just test whether the character is a `,` or a `*`.

Comment: Did you not find any results when searching for information on splitting strings in C++? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: I had need only a help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I have found the solution:

```
while (client.available()) { 
   delay(3);
   char c = client.read();
   readString += c;
} 
readString.trim();
int i1 = readString.indexOf(",");
int i2 = readString.indexOf("*");
int i3 = readString.indexOf("/");
String 1= readString.substring(0, i1--);
String 2= readString.substring(i1 + 2, i2); 
String 3= readString.substring(i2 + 3, i3--);
```